# Which aircraft is this?

Tags: aircraft-identification, biplane

I was curious if someone could help me gather some more info on this aircraft.  I have looked it up in the FAA.GOV site and it does not match.  Is there a way to find out info on this plane that flew around the Springfield Illinois area around 1946, possibly before?  Also, this is a Stearman?  Is there anything else interesting or remarkable about this aircraft?  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [Boeing Stearman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing-Stearman_Model_75) to me.

I couldn't find anything based on the registration (NC55383) of the aircraft.

[image]

<sub>Source: [wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:N2S-2_NAS_Corpus_Christi_1943.jpg) / scan from Robert L. Lawson (ed.): The History of US Naval Air Power. The Military Press, New York (USA), 1985. ISBN 0-517-414813, p. 72. US Navy cited as source.</sub>